# Symfony2 - How can do rewrite this doctrine query without leftJoin statement

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using a query for selecting posts by type. This has a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship with Type to Post.

How can I rewrite this without using a leftJoin statement?

This query works and gets post by type title, but would like to re-write it if the join is not necessary.

query

```
public function getPostsByType($type)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
    ->leftJoin('post.type','type')
    ->andWhere('type.title = :type')
    ->setParameter('type', $type)
    ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

post

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $type;
```

type

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="type")
 */
protected $posts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `Post` by `Type` `id`, like this:

```
public function getPostsByType($type)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
    ->where('post.type = :typeId')
    ->setParameter('typeId', $type->getId())
    ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```